# Why there is no "internal microphone" in my QuickTime player screen recoding audio source?

Tags: audio, quicktime, microphone

I have 3 macs, 2 of them are fine but one of it doesn't have the Internal Microphone recording option in Quick Time Player. Only the other 2 have.

How can I fix this?

The MacOS are all 10.14.3 Mojave and the Mac is Mid 2015. The other two are 2018 and 2017.

Comment: Can you give the exact models - Mini? Macbook Pro? Air? iMac? Also, does the microphone show up in System Preferences > Sound as a listed input device?

Comment: It's a Macbook Pro. Retina 15inch.

Comment: It's not in the Input device, nor in the output device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the microphone is not listed as an Input device in System Prefs, then that's a larger problem than just QuickTime Player: the OS can't access the mic at all.

Assuming you've turned the Mac off and on already, you could try [resetting the NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204063).

You might see whether updating to Mojave 10.14.6 improves matters.

Beyond that, it's likely to be a hardware issue. Is it possible that anyone's opened up the insides for a battery replacement, or other issue? Perhaps they didn't put the cable back properly.

Comment: But I can hear the sound (clear and loud enough), does this mean the problem is not as serious as a hardware one?

Comment: So you can record using the microphone, you just can't select it? OK, that rules out a physical issue. I'd try resetting the NVRAM.

Comment: Do I need to backup my data before resetting the NVRAM?

Comment: You always need a backup, under any circumstances. ;-)  But the reset shouldn't affect the data on the disk.

Comment: Also, if that doesn't work, try updating to the latest build of Mojave.